# insert array string values to database single field not id

Tags: php, mysql

```
$lid= mysql_insert_id();

 $lid= mysql_insert_id();                  
$cityid = trim(ucwords(strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']))));

$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['place'] as $val)
{
    $ids[] = (int) $val;
}
$ids = implode(',', $ids);

$sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `city_place`(`state_id`,`city_id`,`spaid`) VALUES ('$cityid','$ids',$lid)");
```

instead of that city_id i want to store string values?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: instead of that city_id i want to store string values means what?

Comment: above this query i added city_id as in array same like i want to store string values.how?and which datatype i have to use

Comment: INSERT INTO `city_place`(`state_id`,`city_id`,`spaid`) VALUES ('11','12,13,14',24)"));          instead of that INSERT INTO `city_place`(`state_id`,`city_id`,`spaid`) VALUES ('11', '"string","string2","string3"' ,24)")); like that

Comment: Make varchar field you can save string on varchar field.

Comment: longtext i used but its storing id only

Answer (score 0):

your query is working fine.
you should change data type of "city_id" from int to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lid= mysql_insert_id();

$lid= mysql_insert_id();                  
$cityid = trim(ucwords(strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']))));

$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['place'] as $key =>$val) // change this line
{
    $ids[] = (int) $key; // change this line
}
$ids = implode(',', $ids);

$sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `city_place`(`state_id`,`city_id`,`spaid`) VALUES     ('$cityid','$ids',$lid)");
```

Comment: it works,i find the mistake in my form
 
<input type="checkbox"  name="place[]" value="<?=$row['city_id']?>" /><span><?=$row['city']?></span>

here i changed value=city_id to city thne now it works fine